# How to COMMENT in xml file ( in android studio layout file)?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am a beginner at writing xml file and it different to C and C++. So, anyone can show me how to comment in this file?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [html comment tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) like this:

```
<!--This is a comment. -->
```

But please be aware that if you add a comment in an android xml tag like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   <!--WARNING This is not a valid comment. -->
/>
```

Android Studio layout editor will give you an **error**. You can only add it ***outside the xml*** tag like this:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <!--This is a valid comment. -->

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<!-- your comment here -->`

this is just like html commentting

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
    <!--This is a comment-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
```